# grails redirect login page to https on localhost using spring security

Tags: grails, spring-security

I cannot get my app to redirect the login page from http to https in my development environment on localhost.  Is this by design of the spring security plugin?

I run my development environment out of intellij.  When I start my app the command line has

```
-https
```

and when the server starts a message shows:

```
Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/ or https://localhost:8443/
```

I can go to `https://localhost:8443/login/auth` in a browser and the pages of my app shows as secure.  When I type in `http://localhost:8080/login/auth` the browser does NOT get redirected to the secure page.

In config.groovy:

```
environments {
    development {
        grails.server.port.https=8443
        grails.server.host="localhost"
        grails.plugin.springsecurity.secureChannel.useHeaderCheckChannelSecurity = true
        grails.plugin.springsecurity.portMapper.httpPort = 8080
        grails.plugin.springsecurity.portMapper.httpsPort = 8443
        grails.plugin.springsecurity.secureChannel.secureHeaderName = 'X-Forwarded-Proto'
        grails.plugin.springsecurity.secureChannel.secureHeaderValue = 'http'
        grails.plugin.springsecurity.secureChannel.insecureHeaderName = 'X-Forwarded-Proto'
        grails.plugin.springsecurity.secureChannel.insecureHeaderValue = 'https'
...
```

and

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.secureChannel.definition = [
        '/':                'REQUIRES_INSECURE_CHANNEL',
        '/index':           'REQUIRES_INSECURE_CHANNEL',
        '/index.gsp':       'REQUIRES_INSECURE_CHANNEL',
        '/images/**':       'ANY_CHANNEL',
        '/img/**':          'ANY_CHANNEL',
        '/js/**':           'ANY_CHANNEL',
        '/css/**':          'ANY_CHANNEL',
        '/login/**':                        'REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL',
...
```

Does the redirect work for anyone else?  I'm not running the app from a war file, and production works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

I use this property:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.auth.forceHttps = true
```

And the `/login` path is not in the `secureChannel` definitions. It works for me locally.

Comment: I tried your combination but the redirect still doesn't occur on localhost.  Do you have any other relevant springsecurity settings that might be a factor?

Comment: try setting this to false in development: `grails.plugins.springsecurity.secureChannel.useHeaderCheckChannelSecurity = false`

Comment: No luck there either @advais.